# Not able to access WSO2 IoTS Device Management Console in wso2-iot-3.3.0 when logged in 'admin'

Tags: authentication, wso2, iot

I am studying IOT-server. I have a question and please help me. 
I use WSO2 IoT server and I am not able to access WSO2 IoT server device Management Console (https://localhost:9443/devicemgt) when I input 'admin' both username and password or input this which created a new account.
As a result, it showed me the Authentication failed. When I saw users list in https://localhost:9443/carbon, it showed admin, new accounts .... etc. 
I don't know why it does not log in  WSO2 IoT server device Management Console.
Please give your advice and then thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check Java version, All wso2 Products have issues with the latest version of Java, if you are using `java version "1.8.0_151"` then that's a problem, try using `java version "1.8.0_144"`.
If you cannot change java version then you need to change the `compression parameter to off` in `catalina-server.xml` file

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried that. I saw java version "1.8.0_181" and compression ="off" . I modified that. Perfectly it does well. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Welcome, can you accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others as well.