# Authentication Error when Trying to Log into WSO2 IoT Server - Device Management Console in wso2-iot-3.3.0

Tags: wso2

I followed the instructions in the link (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IOTS330/Enterprise+IoT+solution) in Windows to start WSO2 IoT server. So, broker, iot-server and analytics are started. But, when I'm trying to log in to the device management console using admin login or the login credentials I created, it gives me an authentication error.

I tried the solutions in this answer ([Not able to access WSO2 IoTS Device Management Console in wso2-iot-3.3.0 when logged in 'admin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778318/not-able-to-access-wso2-iots-device-management-console-in-wso2-iot-3-3-0-when-lo)) also (Reducing Java version to 1.8.0_144 and making the compression parameter to off in all the catalina-server.xml files). But any of it didn't work for me.

I have attached the screen shots of the error. Please help me to go through this! Thank you.

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPyn9.png)

[Error description in iot-server console-Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdAAE.png)

[Error description in iot-server console-Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fooc8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the issue mentioned in the github issue mentioned below and it seems, it is already fixed in latest master.

As a quick workaround you could try to modify the startup script files (bat files in this case) and add the changes mentioned in the above git issue.

For example, you can change the file `modules/distribution/src/core/bin/iot-server.bat` at line number 73 as below.

```
FOR %%D in ("%CARBON_HOME%\wso2\lib\commons-lang*.jar") DO set CARBON_CLASSPATH=!CARBON_CLASSPATH!;".\wso2\lib\%%~nD%%~xD"
```

Similarly do the same change as above for files mentioned below as well.

`modules/distribution/src/core/resources/profiles/backend/iot-server.bat`
`modules/distribution/src/core/resources/profiles/keymanager/iot-server.bat`
`modules/distribution/src/core/resources/profiles/manager/iot-server.bat`

This should resolve the issues you are facing.

Related github issue - https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/pull/1838/files